# Segmentation violation detected in Matlab2016a on Ubuntu15.10

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-15.10

I get this error when starting Matlab2016a on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit. How can I fix it?

```
MATLAB crash file:/home/jalal/matlab_crash_dump.8510-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Wed Aug 31 20:50:17 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.21 stable
  Host Name           : klein
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.2.0-42-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:26:26 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11702000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f7a44573808
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 0000000000000003
  RSP = 00007f7b3bdf3cd0  RBP = 00007f7b3bdf3df0
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f7a4456f9e8

   R8 = 0000000000000018   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 00007f7a4456f000  R11 = 00007f7a44574450
  R12 = 00007f7a4478ff80  R13 = 0000000000000006
  R14 = 00007f7a44570cc0  R15 = 00007f7aa82b4a60

  RIP = 00007f7b5ce778ca  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f7b5ce778ca                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00051402
[  1] 0x00007f7b5ce804c1                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087233
[  2] 0x00007f7b5ce7b474                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066676
[  3] 0x00007f7b5ce7f9b3                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084403
[  4] 0x00007f7b5a528fc9                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004041
[  5] 0x00007f7b5ce7b474                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066676
[  6] 0x00007f7b5a52962d                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005677
[  7] 0x00007f7b5a529061                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004193 dlopen+00000049
[  8] 0x00007f7b56d740b6      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00315574
[  9] 0x00007f7b56d74c76      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318582 _Z11utGetModuleRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPi+00000022
[ 10] 0x00007f7b56d74d6b      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318827 utGetModule+00000171
[ 11] 0x00007f7b4a1f9d45 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00482629
[ 12] 0x00007f7b4a1eceaf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00429743 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000031
[ 13] 0x00007f7b4a1e3e95 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00392853 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 14] 0x00007f7b4a1e15e9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00382441 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000057
[ 15] 0x00007f7b472261c9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09232841
[ 16] 0x00007f7b47352dbf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10464703
[ 17] 0x00007f7b47348a5a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10422874
[ 18] 0x00007f7b47311911 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10197265
[ 19] 0x00007f7b46ddfb2a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04750122
[ 20] 0x00007f7b46de0a4c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04753996
[ 21] 0x00007f7b46ddeebc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746940
[ 22] 0x00007f7b46ddc9ea /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04737514
[ 23] 0x00007f7b46ddcdb1 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04738481
[ 24] 0x00007f7b46ddea63 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04745827
[ 25] 0x00007f7b46ddebe9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746217
[ 26] 0x00007f7b46e8f16f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05468527
[ 27] 0x00007f7b46e9222a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05481002
[ 28] 0x00007f7b47134543 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08242499
[ 29] 0x00007f7b470fd07e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08015998
[ 30] 0x00007f7b47101058 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032344
[ 31] 0x00007f7b47101107 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032519
[ 32] 0x00007f7b4717732c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08516396
[ 33] 0x00007f7b4717770c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08517388
[ 34] 0x00007f7b49bfad7d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03165565 _Z51inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPibbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000077
[ 35] 0x00007f7b4a8739e1   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00825825 _ZNK3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin24inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnERKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000081
[ 36] 0x00007f7b4a873b58   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00826200 _ZN3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000120
[ 37] 0x00007f7afe767ee4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00974564 _ZN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000340
[ 38] 0x00007f7afe78dedd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+01130205 _ZN3mcr3mvm27McrSwappingIqmPluginAdapterIN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPluginEE7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000429
[ 39] 0x00007f7b4a866f98   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00774040
[ 40] 0x00007f7b4a850c87   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00683143
[ 41] 0x00007f7b496c87a9 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00173993
[ 42] 0x00007f7b496c8c44 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00175172
[ 43] 0x00007f7b496cf1a5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00201125
[ 44] 0x00007f7b496cf2ac /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00201388
[ 45] 0x00007f7b496cf97b /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00203131 _Z8mnParserv+00000715
[ 46] 0x00007f7b4a523c13   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00695315
[ 47] 0x00007f7b5c80d81c   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so+02410524 _ZNK5boost9function0IvEclEv+00000028
[ 48] 0x00007f7b4a525925   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00702757
[ 49] 0x00007f7b4a526839   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00706617 _ZN5boost6detail17task_shared_stateINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEvE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 50] 0x00007f7b572ee8a0    /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+03168416 _ZN5boost6detail22task_base_shared_stateIvE3runEv+00000064
[ 51] 0x00007f7b4a527717   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00710423
[ 52] 0x00007f7b4a52375a   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00694106
[ 53] 0x00007f7b4a896c06   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00969734
[ 54] 0x00007f7b4a884b4c   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00895820 _ZN5boost6detail8function21function_obj_invoker0ISt8functionIFNS_3anyEvEES4_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE+00000028
[ 55] 0x00007f7b4a88521f   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00897567 _ZNK5boost9function0INS_3anyEEclEv+00000031
[ 56] 0x00007f7b4a884993   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00895379 _ZN3iqm18PackagedTaskPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000163
[ 57] 0x00007f7b4a53871d   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00780061
[ 58] 0x00007f7b4a866f98   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00774040
[ 59] 0x00007f7b4a8515af   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00685487
[ 60] 0x00007f7b4a84e7e3   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00673763
[ 61] 0x00007f7b5c1caa3a /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03443258
[ 62] 0x00007f7b5c1c98a7 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03438759
[ 63] 0x00007f7b5c1ca10c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03440908 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000092
[ 64] 0x00007f7b4a523ed2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696018
[ 65] 0x00007f7b4a524211   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696849
[ 66] 0x00007f7b4a510cfd   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00617725
[ 67] 0x00007f7b5acff6aa              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030378
[ 68] 0x00007f7b5aa3513d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01077565 clone+00000109
[ 69] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem this way using the instructions in [MathWorks bug reports](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1297894):

```
jalal@klein:~$ cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/
jalal@klein:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a$ cd sys/os/glnxa64/
jalal@klein:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64$ sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
[sudo] password for jalal: 
jalal@klein:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64$ matlab
```

Comment: In 16.04 an alternative is to run `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` and allow it to rename old gcc libraries

Answer (score 0):

After installing matlab-support
I have to run sudo matlab -nodisplay